# VS2017 create a lib for multiple framework targets

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit, .net-standard-1.5

I have a simple Dll where I defined some class like this:

```
public class Parameters 
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I added a NuGet package `Newtonsoft.Json`.

This DLL MUST be consumed by a *netcoreapp1.1* and a *net462*.

I have tried to modify the csproj and added this

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard1.5</TargetFramework>
```

If I launch dotnet build the dll was build successfully but I cannot consume the DLL from the netcore app neither from net462

In particular if I add a `xUnit` test and reference a class inside the DLL it raise the error:

> `System.IO.FileLoadException`: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0 [..]

Anybody can explain me how work `net462`, `netcoreapp` and `netstandard1.5` target frameworks? And how build a dll cross framework?

**UPDATE**

For find the related assembly must be add the code below on xunit .csproj

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

Comment: you can add several frameworks in <TargetFramework>, separated by semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a table for `.Net Standard` platforms support [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library). You need to understand that `.Net Standard` is **not** a framework, it's a rules for libraries to implement for `.Net Standard` support.

So, if you need your library to support both `.Net Core` and `.Net Framework` 4.6, you [need to target `.Net Standard` 1.6.1 (!)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40660374/213550), not 1.5 or 1.6, **and** `.Net Framework`, [according to this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/) (note plural form of tag).

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6.1;net462</TargetFrameworks>
```

Maybe it will work without the `net462`, as it should support 1.6 version, I'll update later for this.

Also I found `xUnit` blog post about [running tests against multiple targets](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core#multi-targeting), they used this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net452;netcoreapp1.1</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that they've targeted the `netcoreapp`, not the `netstandard`.

Comment: I have modified the tag like this `<TargetFrameworks>net462;netcoreapp1.1</TargetFrameworks>` and now compile and run. I have found the github netstandard link to [netstandard table](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) but I think there is some confusion in Microsoft.

Comment: xUnit continue to raise the error about cannot find the dll, but if I write a simple console program it run

Comment: I think MS simply waits for a 2.0 version for the standard

Comment: @Max related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42364427/213550 You have to target multiple networks